# How to search single quotes in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I have the value of this `RBC's`. I want to use my choose statement to search for that specific value.

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.MICROSCOPYRESULTNAME = ''
```

How can I search that particular value using my above query?

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL, when you have a string literal that includes a single quote, you escape the single quote with itself:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable mt WHERE mt.MICROSCOPYRESULTNAME = 'RBC''s'
```

Note that when building these queries from code in a client language like java, php, etc, you should **NEVER** do this. Instead, include the value via a parameterized query/prepared statement. Then the query parameter will handle including the value in a safe way, regardless of what special characters it may have.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, empty string `''` represents `NULL`, so that condition should be `is null`.

```
SQL> select * from mytable;

MICROSCOPYRESULTNAME         ID
-------------------- ----------
                              1
ABC                           2
RBC's                         3

SQL> select * from mytable where microscopyresultname = '';

no rows selected

SQL> select * from mytable where microscopyresultname is null;

MICROSCOPYRESULTNAME         ID
-------------------- ----------
                              1

SQL>
```

If it is about a single quote, then you can either *double* it, or use the q-quoting mechanism which makes things simpler, especially when you have to deal with a lot of single quotes (query becomes difficult to maintain):

```
SQL> select * from mytable where microscopyresultname = q'[RBC's]';

MICROSCOPYRESULTNAME         ID
-------------------- ----------
RBC's                         3

SQL> select * from mytable where microscopyresultname = 'RBC''s';

MICROSCOPYRESULTNAME         ID
-------------------- ----------
RBC's                         3

SQL>
```